# Android splliting video picture into parts

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I need to split video picture into 4 parts and display video picturesome part in video-view. is this possible.

Comment: take screenshot of your video while playing in 4 times

Comment: not understand can you please elaborate. i want to split video picture like "http://kalanir.blogspot.in/2010/02/how-to-split-image-into-chunks-java.html?m=1 ;" this link.

Comment: But this i a image and i want this feature with video picture.

Comment: what? video picture means?

Comment: Like i have a video , i am playing that video in 4 different screen and all the screens will play video at the same time.
Now if i join all the device screen then it become the complete picture of video.

Comment: like, 4 phones play 1/4 part of video, and join all device make whole video right?

Comment: yes , but videos is played complete but the picture is divided.means 4 devices has 4 complete video size but the picture means screen is splitted.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting your video into 4 parts, you could send the full video to each device and then only display the part you want for that particular device.

Using a TextureView and a matrix transformation will allow you 'zoom' in on the quarter of the video you want to display on the p[articular device.

This approach is a tradeoff - you avoid having to do the server side processing to split the video, but you are increasing the bandwith you need as you are sending the full video to each device.

Note that you will also have to solve the problem of synching the video playback on the devices - there is an old example Android project on GitHub which does this. It it not maintained anymore but should be a useful starting point: https://github.com/blinkendroid/blinkendroid

Comment: Thanks for the help , i would need below feature with android device
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXreofJxeX8&feature=youtu.be
Can this is possible.